# How to make a macro that takes a formatted string + several additional arguments, just like NSLog?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

This is for practise. I try to build something similar to NSLog. Currently I have this:

```
#define LogThis(info) \
    [[MyLogger sharedLogger] logThis:info];\


- (void)logThis:(NSString*)info {
    fprintf(stderr, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@\n", info] cString]);
}
```

Currently all I can do is pass a simple `@"string"` to it, but no formats and arguments like I could with NSLog. The main advantage here is that I get rid of all this overhead which NSLog produces. For learning purpose I'd like to know how I can get multiple arguments to make something similar to NSLog, so that I could call:

```
LogThis(@"method foo received input value %d", inputValue)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s how you define variadic macros in gcc’s cpp:

```
#define LogThis(format, ...) \
    do { printf(format, ## __VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
```

Comment: wouldnt this just print out all my arguments separately?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, you define the last argument with a trailing '...'. To access the last arguments defined, prepend the argument name with ##. I have a similar Log macro that looks like:

```
#define LOGGER(format, args...)                                   \
    LogManager::log()->addEntry(format, ##args)
```

where the addEntry function takes in a printf-like format. An example call looks like

```
LOGGER("This is a debug string with %d arguments %s", 2, "hooray");
```